# How to install Intel Media Accelerator Driver in Ubuntu 12?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, display, brightness

I have always been windows user, this is the first time i have switched to anything other than windows. The problem is that the display is very very dark and i know it has nothing to do with my monitor's settings. I get the same problem whenever i re install windows on my desktop but it gets solved when i install  Intel Media Accelerator and increase brightness from there. But i do not know where to go, what to download and how to install? Please just help me out with getting rid of this dark screen.

```
Name:Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family
Chip Type: Intel(R) GMA 3100
```

Comment: What PC or laptop/netbook are you using? What is the exact chip/card for graphics? (eg. GMA3400) *Try command **`sudo lshw`***

Comment: Name:Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family
Chip Type: Intel(R) GMA 3100

Comment: Processor, form-factor (laptop, AIO, netbook)?

Comment: I am using a desktop which has asrock mother board , dual core.

Comment: What is your motherboard model no.

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score -1):

The Intel Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Linux, can be downloaded [Here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/confirm.aspx?httpDown=http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19158/a08/Intel-GMA500-5%5B1%5D.0.0.0040.tar.gz&lang=eng&Dwnldid=19158).

Once downloaded, you need to extract the file, and install it.  For instructions on how to install .tar.gz, see [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

You need to use the Ubuntu Mobile & Embedded (UME) file to install.  Also you can look at the Readme_gfx.txt for installation instructions.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded that file and then extracted it, it turns out that it in turn gave me 3 folders each one has many tar files

Comment: Look at the info I added in the answer, hope it works for you.